# How to make Skim's backward search accurate for multiline equations

Tags: latex, sublimetext3

I have been using Sublime 2/3 together with Skim for Latex for a long time, however, since I have a lot long derivations (equations which is half-page long), I found it is annoying when I use backward sync to jump back to tex file.

For example, I have a five-line align environment in Latex, and I want to correct one line of it. If I press command+shift+left mouse click on Mac for backward search, the cursor jumps to the end of align environment instead of the correct line.

I found my colleague uses TexStudio on Windows and the backward search works perfect, so I wonder if it is possible to improve the backward search for Sublime+Skim. I really like Sublime so I don't wanna switch to another Latex editor.

Comment: I found the reason, my colleague uses IEEEeqnarray and it works perfect with backward search. However it seems many answers in StackExchange recommends to avoid eqnarray. Further experiment showed that environment equation+aligned works perfectly and I can use this as an alternative for align environment. The only thing annoying is using this I cannot have numbering for each line

Comment: Update: It seems that IEEEeqnarray solves most drawbacks of eqnarray, see section IX of http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf, it is better to use IEEEeqnarray instead of align